# git branch doesn't show all my branches created in my newly created repo in local

Tags: git

Why it doesn't not show all my current branches after i created a local repository?. I used **git branch** and **git branch -a** command.
This is in git current version 2.14 for windows

So initial branch is the master ,then i created a "test"  branch

But after i use the command **git branch** it doesn't show the branches master and test

Comment: What does `git branch -vv` show you?

Comment: You need to be more specific with you question. After creating local repo what all branches did you create ?

Comment: Provide more details

Answer (score -1):

For reference since i didn't not see any for this question which i already solved.

step 1 : after i creation of repo on my/your local
step 2 : commit first to include the master branch
step 3 : then create your first branch and commit
step 4 : then try git branch or git branch -a

cheers !!